# When creating a new instance, how do I check if it's a duplicate and if so return the original pointer?

Tags: java

I have a class called Token, which instantiates with `new Token(String)`. Because the Token class generates a random number when instantiating, it is important there is only one Token instance for every String input. For guaranteeing such a behavior I would like to return the original instance pointer when trying to create a dupicate instance.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `TokenFactory` class that has a `Map<String, Token>` data member.  In your create method, pass back the value if you find the `String` as a key in the `Map`.  If not, add it to the `Map` before returning.

If you want to prevent users from creating `Token` instances on their own, you'll have to try making the constructor private and making the `TokenFactory` a static inner class, like a `Builder` pattern.

```
public class TokenFactory {
    private static final Map<String, Token> INSTANCES = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Token>();

    public Token create(String key) {
        if (INSTANCES.containsKey(key) { 
            return INSTANCES.get(key);
        } else {
            Token t = new Token(key);
            INSTANCES.put(key, t);
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap isn't acceptable?  If not, by all means synchronize it.

Answer (score 1):

If your Token class is immutable you could consider using [Interner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) from Google Guava. From the javadoc:

> Chooses and returns the representative instance for any of a collection of instances that are equal to each other. If two equal inputs are given to this method, both calls will return the same instance. That is, intern(a).equals(a) always holds, and intern(a) == intern(b) if and only if a.equals(b). Note that intern(a) is permitted to return one instance now and a different instance later if the original interned instance was garbage-collected.

For example

```
Interner<Token> tokenInterner = Interners.newStrongInterner();
Token token = tokenInterner.intern(new Token("String"));
```

would ensure that the same Token instance is always returned for the same String value (assuming you implement equals correctly).